# If Statement to check whether a folder contains files

Tags: c#, file, if-statement, move

I need an if statement to check whether a *folder contains files*. I have tried a few things but I cannot get it to work if there are files *within a subfolder* in the root folder. Do I have to have a *loop* to look in the *subfolders*? Here's what I have so far:

```
if(Directory.GetDirectories(oldDir).Length == 0 && Directory.GetFiles(oldDir).Length == 0)
{
   //do this
}
```

I was hoping it would pick up folders that doesn't contain any file in it. (weather it has a subfolder or not)

Comment: This is a good case for recursion. Call your function with the top level dir, and have it call it's self for each child dir, checking for more sub directories and more files.

Comment: Yes, you will have to loop over the sub-folders, and as those sub-folders might contain their own folders, you've got a perfect situation for a recursive function.

Comment: See [GetFiles(String, String, SearchOption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_), where `SearchOptions` can be set to `AllDirectories` : _"Includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points such as mounted drives and symbolic links in the search."_ For GetDirectories, there is also a version with SearchOptions

Comment: @Fildor in this case I would use EnumerateFiles as, per the question, we do not need a complete list/count of all files. So a call to `FirstOrDefault() != null` should be faster.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Absolutely agreed. And there also the version with SearchOptions.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to get *all the files* / directories with `GetFiles` (imagine if we want to know whether we have files in `c:\`). We can try to start enumerating files and check if we have `Any` of them. If we want to examing  *subfolders* we can add `SearchOption.AllDirectories` option:

```
// Do we have any file - "*" in any directory or sub directory  
if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(oldDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any()) {    
  //do this
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by recursion like this:

```
      public bool ContainsFiles(string dirName)
      {
         if (Directory.GetFiles(dirName).Any()) return true;
         return Directory.GetDirectories(dirName).Any(subDir => ContainsFiles(subDir));
      }
```